# Angular ngfor alternative by using index?

Tags: angular

**Requirement:**

I want to transpose some data of the following form to weekly view

**Input:**

```
Product date amount 
A 2019-04-10 $100
B 2019-04-11 $200
```

**Output:**

```
Project Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri 

A           100
B.                 200
```

I also want to keep the `ngModel` binding.

**Solution:**

I am thinking of doing this by using the **array index** for the binding but not sure if this will work?

Any suggestions appreciated

Comment: can you provide your code which you done so far.

Comment: can you share some example of the data ?

Comment: you need get the day of the week of each element (better using a forEach in .ts to add the new property) and use some like {{element.dayOfweek==0?element.amount:''}} for each td